# How to build Spring Roo project without maven?

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, m2eclipse, spring-roo

How to build Spring Roo project without maven?

P.S. I use STS to create Roo project. I use maven for dependency management. Thanks to m2eclipse I have all libraries on eclipse classpath.
I have other non-Maven referenced. So maven fails to build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  Well, I suppose you could manually create an Ant-based build file that would do the same thing, but why?

One of the purposes behind Roo is that it helps manage the dependencies and build processes necessary for your chosen data persistence architecture.  Maven is currently the standard build tool for doing just that, and you get its best practices implemented for you by creating the project via Roo.

Alternatively, if you're just trying to import a Roo-created project into Eclipse try ...

```
roo> perform eclipse
...
```

That will generate Eclipse project files that you can import.

Comment: I have non-Maven project referenced, so Maven fails.
However everything is working ok inside Eclipse, due to m2eclpse.
I just cannot build.

Comment: So can you import your Roo project into Eclipse and use it as the build environment for both projects?  The only concern there is that you may have to re-import the Roo project file(s) if/when you make Roo-related changes (i.e. change the back-end database, etc).  Still it should work, unless I'm missing another detail in your environment.  Please elaborate as necessary!

Comment: I am using STS, so I need not to import anything.
I cant convert or copy reference project as it is still under development.

Answer (score -2):

This is about using custom maven artifacts.

Create a custom Maven repository, place your referenced jars in there and include them as dependencies in your `pom.xml` file.

Learn some Maven, it would really help - specially when working with Roo.